# pip install tensorflow cannot find file called client_load_reporting_filter.h

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, pip, package

I keep failing to run `pip install` on the **tensorflow** package. First it downloads the .whl file, then goes through a bunch of already satisfied requirements until it gets to `installing collected packages: tensorflow`, at which point here's the error I get:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Borik\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include\\external\\com_github_grpc_grpc\\src\\core\\ext\\filters\\client_channel\\lb_policy\\grpclb\\client_load_reporting_filter.h'
```

I've never seen anything like this before and can't seem to find anything on the net. I'm using Windows 10 and the latest versions of Python and pip.

Comment: I would ask if you installed Python separately, or if that is the default Python installation that comes with Windows? I would advise a fresh Python installation outside of `AppData\Local`. You also don't say if you are using pip from the command line, or from within an IDE. If you could add a fresh venv to go with it all the better...

Comment: I suspect the path is too long (291 characters). Try re-installing Python closer to the root of the filesystem.

Comment: @phd is that safe? where would you re-install it to if you had to?

Comment: @chocojunkie I almost never in my life use Windows but when I do (in a VirtualBox) I always install into the root. If I don't have write-access I'd try `C:\Users\phd\Python38`

Comment: @phd iwould it be possible to rename some of the folders instead? for instance, there's the `AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0`, maybe I could somehow change that last one to just `Python`

Comment: @chocojunkie Then you have to fix registry — all keys related to Python paths.

Comment: @chocojunkie, Also, please ensure that your system meets all the Software and Hardware requirements listed in the link, https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements. Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I hit the same issue on Win10. Rather than renaming my filesystem, I found a good solution in [this Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html).   To summarize the instructions there to change MAX_PATH, either:

- Enable the "Enable Win32 long paths" group policy:

  - Run `gpedit` (or searching for "Edit Group Policy" in the Control Panel)
  - Find the "Enable Win32 long paths" option in the sidebar.  It should be under *Local Computer Policy* -> *Computer Configuration* -> *Administrative Templates* -> *System* -> *Filesystem* (under both Windows 10 and Windows 11, currently).
- Or edit the registry setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` and set `LongPathsEnabled` to `1`.

This extends path from char(256) to char(32000).  After this change, my 'pip install tensorflow' succeeded.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure how I would have found this otherwise! +1

Comment: Damn ! You probably save my entire afternoon ! Thank you +1

Comment: Cheers man! This was the most useful answer ever!

Comment: While useful information (apparently) to a number of people, please remember to summarize all links so that your answer is still useful even if the link changes in the future.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) for more details.  I've edited your answer to add this, but please just keep it in mind for future answers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in Windows 10.

I have downloaded Python 3.10 and installed it with PATH.

I found that there is a duplicate installation for Python 3.10 (the same from the Windows Store app. My solution was to uninstall the application of Python from the Windows Store.

You don't have this folder in your PC:

```
C:\Users\<yourName>\AppData\Local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0
```