# How much space is necessary to install tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, pip, jupyter

I'm trying to run `pip install tensorflow` from a **jupyter notebook** (trying to run it with **cmd** gives out an even stranger [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404192/pip-install-tensorflow-cannot-find-file-called-client-load-reporting-filter-h?noredirect=1#comment112115098_63404192)), and my free disk space (currently 1.2 GB left) seems to dwindle during installation and then I'm presented with `[Errno 28] No space left on device`. Then it goes back to what it was.

Answer (score 4):

This will certainly help using pip install and build:

`pip install --cache-dir=/data/jimit/ --build /data/jimit/ tensorflow-gpu TMPDIR==/data/jimit/`

What it does is:

> pip downloads files to temporary directory, environment variable
> TMPDIR specifies that directory, also pip puts files into cache thus
> --cache-dir specification, --no-cache-dir should work too. --build specifies directory where wheel will be built, so its specification is
> also useful.

Please Note: /data/jimit are directory so please name it according to your preferences.

Comment: I get `'TMPDIR' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @chocojunkie I updated the code, run the code now in your command prompt with administrator privileges or from your IDE.

Comment: Also do the `pip install --upgrade pip` before running that.

Comment: @chocojunkie If it helped, please mark this answer as accepted, it'd help others decide too and help me gain reputation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Wanting to import it myself to a ML PyCharm project, I googled and run across the same issue. Using pip it will *cost* your disk **1.1 GB approx**. So, if you have 1.2 GB size left in your disk, it makes sense that the installation stucks.

If you are familiar with the functions/classes of the tensorflow package, I'd recommend to install certain libraries. For example in an IDE - in your import section - you can use:

`from tensorflow import test`

That way, only **test** needed packages from **tensorflow** platform will be installed

Or using the answer from Jimit you can pip certain packages using the parameters. For further information regarding the use of pip you can also take a look here:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/

Answer (score 0):

Jimit's answer didn't work for me. Instead I had to follow this [example](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/d80zyo/when_pip_installing_python3_m_pip_can_i_use/), which mentions:

```
 export TMPDIR='/work/tmp_other'; python3 -m pip install gooey
```

Which would change Jimit's answer to this:

```
export TMPDIR='/data/jimit/'; pip install --cache-dir=/data/jimit/ tensorflow-gpu
```

where `/data/jimit/` is a custom directory.